# Is there an Autofac Module for SystemWrapper in existence?

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, autofac, .net

There is a .NET library for wrapping System calls named [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/). I'm using it to enable me to mock out System.IO calls in a project that uses Autofac. Rather than have to write out the registration for all the SystemWrapper types that I'm using, I wonder: Is there already an Autofac registration Module that I can plug in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you write your own module? With a little help from Autofac's RegisterAssemblyTypes.
http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning

Comment: You make a good point. It's not worth having a module given that it's possible in one line using this method!